# Pandas : Percentage of nan for each value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Objective : Get missing values as percentage for each column of a df and for each client

My df is about created tickets :

```
          id                type  ...      priority          Client
0     56 113            Incident  ...          Low           client1
1     56 267             Demande  ...          High          client1
2     56 294            Incident  ...          Nan           NaN
3     56 197             Demande  ...          Low           client3
4     56 143             Demande  ...          Nan           client4
```

first attempt :

```
df.notna().sum()/len(agg_global)*100
Out[29]:                       
id                       97.053453   
type                     76.415869   
priority                 82.626625    
client                   84.596443
```

That's very useful but i would like to add more details to my output with 'Client' dimension in column like this :

Output i would like to create :

```
                           Client1   Client2     Client3      NaN
id                      100.000000   100.000000  100.000000   66.990424
type                     76.415869   66.990424   76.415869    43.761970
status                  100.000000   100.000000  66.990424    76.415869
category                66.990424   43.761970   76.415869     43.761970
entity                   43.761970   100.000000  76.415869    76.415869
source_demande           84.596443   100.000000  76.415869    43.761970
```

I tried to use "groupby" but i could not obtain the desire output ... :

```
                   id       type  ...      priority         Client
client                            ...                             
True        97.053453  76.415869  ...      29.98632       29.98632
```

Any Advice will be appreciated. Thank you for your attention !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove column `Client` for not testing percentage of missing values, test them by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html), aggregate mean by `Client` with replace `NaN`s for avoid lost them, and last transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
print (df)
       id      type priority   Client
0     NaN  Incident      Low  client1
1     NaN       NaN     High  client1
2  56 294  Incident      Nan      NaN
3  56 197       NaN      Low  client3
4     NaN   Demande      NaN  client4


df = (df.drop('Client', 1)
        .isna()
        .groupby(df['Client'].fillna('NaN'))
        .mean()
        .rename_axis(None)
        .T)
print (df)
          NaN  client1  client3  client4
id        0.0      1.0      0.0      1.0
type      0.0      0.5      1.0      0.0
priority  0.0      0.0      0.0      1.0
```

Comment: Thank you Sir ! That's exactly what I expected !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see it's possible to do using brute-force. I would try to use the [isna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) function and summation to estimate the number of NaNs in each row or column, then I'd try to estimate percentages.